# Typescript doesn't narrow types in case of explicit object keys and string type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have next setup:

```js
export const PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS = {
  'Int': 'number',
  'BigInt': 'number',
  'Decimal': 'number',
  'Float': 'number',
  'String': 'string',
  'Bytes': 'string',
  'Boolean': 'boolean',
  'DateTime': 'Date',
};


const randomKey: string = "randomKey"; // value can be different

if (PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS.hasOwnProperty(randomKey)) {
  // here is TS error "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type"
  console.log('type is good', PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS[randomKey]);
} else {
  console.log('value is not good');
}
```

The problem is that typescript doesn't narrow types after check with
`PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS.hasOwnProperty(randomKey)`

What can be other ways of narrowing types for such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the signature of `hasOwnProperty`:

```
hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean;
```

It has no predicate, it's not a type guard so the compiler won't narrow anything.

As it is not possible to write a generic type guard, you will need to use a type assertion :

```
if (PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS.hasOwnProperty(randomKey)) {
  // here is TS error "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type"
  console.log('type is good', PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS[randomKey as keyof typeof PRISMA_TYPES_TO_TS]);
} else {
  console.log('value is not good');
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wAoCUCSBlAWQEEB9AFQE0MBRPcgeXLzgF44BvAKDjgHIdkMXgC4%20yAK4BbAEbAovADTc%20AIQCWAcwFDRvCTLmLlvACLAEayQEMANiLFTZ8pT14AxGxCs6HB58bwYKDVkDXtedGDQo1cVAE8YYFRwyJCwl1UICBtgK2Rw6SycvJi%20E29gMktgcPLEowBfAG5OVqQ0eCg8gBMISQBpYDjRVNDWOAAiLuRegaGJprgAeiW4ADdbcWBEPLhZOG61ADMjuWBBVuO4AApsfGJyKloGJgA6AAsrVHoAd2QMKAQMByGBxa7TWaDOIASmhHGUKzg7zOcDUqDgZGYckBUEmADkIKiZqA4KhNMhvOIoNsfmoYO84FY4GArF1JMBEriIEc4KDgXxRmE4D8vnAjhBxDM4CheXFgRNlO1UNlgK9PBprrw%20ds0XANFluoo4HdCKRKDQ6GRGJiANoQvpQxnogDWQ25suB7pND3NzytTAAutCWg04MAbKhtlweEqVWqIBreBsbFtUejkBB4PqIIbg5wGkA)

Comment: And what is the possible option to handle this?
And how can I understand, what is type guard, and what not? How I know, construction like ```typeof x === "string"``` is type guard in case if we have string | number value as an example.

Comment: Did you read this page ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: My fault, thanks for the quick answer. I just thought there were other ways instead of using "is" / "as" operators.